# Python pyglet repeats playing the audio non stop

Tags: python, pyglet

The play sound (should be a short beep) doesn't stop. I made a short test case below.
The IDE is VS2019.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import dlib
from math import hypot
import pyglet
import time

# Load sounds
sound = pyglet.media.load("sound.wav", streaming=False)
left_sound = pyglet.media.load("left.wav", streaming=False)
right_sound = pyglet.media.load("right.wav", streaming=False)
sound.play()
while True:
    print("***")
```

How can I make it play once the beep? (without time measuring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `while True` loop use `pyglet.app.run()`:

```
import pyglet

sound = pyglet.resource.media('sound.wav')
sound.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

See [pyglet documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/quickstart.html#playing-sounds-and-music)

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work as well. The whole point of the loop was to stop the run from going forward, and to test the sound. This did not work as well, so I stopped using pyglet and used winsound instead, which works just fine/